# Firestore add return of function to database

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, cors

I'm trying to create a function with firebase, where upon request the function carries out some scraping activites and then logs the result to a collection each time. My function works and returns the Array of items that I need, but I am having trouble then adding this array to the firestore database.

I am not sure if I need to subscribe to the response or if it is returning something else.
Cloud Function:

```
exports.scraper = functions.https.onRequest( async (request, response) => {
    cors(request, response, async () => {

        const body = (request.body);
        const data = await scrapeteamtags(body.text);
        response.send(data)
    });
    return admin.firestore().collection('games').add({
        teams: data
    })
    
});
```

Added the function used in the await for context:

```
const scrapeteamtags = (text) => {
    const urls = Array.from( getUrls(text) );
    const requests = urls.map(async url => {

        const res = await fetch(url);
        const html = await res.text();
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);
        
        const getTeamlist = JSON.parse($('body').text())  
        
        var gamelist = {
            games: []
        }
    
        getTeamlist.SSResponse.children.map(function(item) {
            // go into the returned json
            var event = new Object;
            var leagues  = ["Premier League", "Spanish La Liga", "Italian Serie A", 'French Ligue 1', 'German Bundesliga']
            // finds all child items that contain the event tag
            
            if(Object.keys(item).includes('event')) {
                // check that the league is on the list which are of interest
                if(leagues.includes(item.event.typeName)) {
                event.id = item.event.id;
                event.name = item.event.name;
                // add the event name and id to the object then go into next level to get market data
                item.event.children.map(function(item1) {
                    if(Object.keys(item1).includes('market')) {
                        event.marketid = item1.market.id
                        // add the market data id to the object
                        var eventoutcome = []

                        item1.market.children.map(function(item2) {
                            if(Object.keys(item2).includes('outcome')) {
                                eventoutcome.push({"id" : item2.outcome.id,
                                "id": item2.outcome.id,
                                "name": item2.outcome.name,
                                "price": item2.outcome.children[0].price.priceDec})
                                //adds the id, name and price to an array, then add it to the object
                                event.outcome = eventoutcome
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
                gamelist.games.push(event)
            }
            // push each event as a new object to the array of games
            
            }
        })

        //console.log(gamelist.games)
        return {
            gamelist

        }
    });
    
    return Promise.all(requests);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP functions don't let you return a promise with the data to send.  (That's how callable functions work, but that doesn't apply here.)  You will have to wait for the database write to finish, then send the response to terminate the function.

The function should be structured more like this:

```
exports.scraper = functions.https.onRequest( async (request, response) => {
    cors(request, response, async () => {
        const body = (request.body);
        const data = await scrapeteamtags(body.text);
        await admin.firestore().collection('games').add({
            teams: data
        })
        response.send(data)
    });
    
});
```